# Is there a better way to create model while the database already have the table

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

In my MySQL database I already have a table `fo_dic`.

```
mysql> desc fo_dic;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| desc     | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| author   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| priority | int(5)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I want to create the FoDic model by Django
for Django Rest Framework to ORM the data.

```
from django.db import models

class FoDic(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField()
    desc = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField()
    priority = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to know whether this will generate migrations when I sync the database, then there will have conflict? 
is there a way to create the Model as the same structure as the MySQL table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have database setup, you can automatically generate models from it:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

You don't need to worry about the conflicts in migrations with this as Django creates it itself.

For more details, please refer to [`this`](https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/creating-django-models-of-an-existing-db-288m).

Comment: Should I cut the content of the generated models.py into my app's models.py file?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Make sure to check for foreign key references. Because with some versions for MySql it might not behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this property to your Meta class

```
Class Meta:
     managed=false
```

Add this your model class